# Generating Difficult List in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make the list of the form

```
[111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133, 211, 212, 213, ...]
```

in Python, but I'm having a lot of difficulty. I was starting with the list

```
[1, 1, 1]
```

and then adding 1 to the last term until it hits `3`, then resetting it to go to the next element of the list and continue from there. I could then create an integer from each list (i.e., `[1,1,1]` becomes `111`). However, I think this is overkill. Is there any easier way to generate a list of this type in Python?

Comment: Show us what you have done.

Comment: too many down vote in this question only for not posting the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this pretty easily:

```
[(a+b+c) for a in range(100,400,100) for b in range(10,40,10) for c in range(1,4,1)]
```

Output:

```
[111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123, 131, 132, 133, 211, 212, 213, 221, 222, 223, 231, 232, 233, 311, 312, 313, 321, 322, 323, 331, 332, 333]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way that easily generalises to different sets of digits and/or longer sequences:

```
In [14]: [int(''.join(l)) for l in itertools.product('123', repeat=3)]
Out[14]: 
[111,
 112,
 113,
 121,
 122,
 123,
 131,
 132,
 133,
 211,
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
tuple_to_int = lambda dd: reduce(lambda rst, d: rst * 10 + d, dd)
print map(tuple_to_int, itertools.product(*([[1, 2, 3]]*3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

More generally, you can use this:

```
def gen_some_numbers(count=None):                                               
   hundreds = 100                                                               
   tens = 10                                                                    
   ones = 0                                                                     
   while count is None or count > 0:                                            
       if count is not None:                                                    
           count -= 1                                                           

       ones += 1                                                                

       if ones > 3:                                                             
           ones = 1                                                             
           tens += 10                                                           

       if tens > 30:                                                            
           tens = 10                                                            
           hundreds += 100                                                      

       yield hundreds + tens + ones                                             


print(list(gen_some_numbers(40)))
```